# How to share a closed source Flutter library written in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have spent months and days to write a library in dart [flutter app], and want to monetize my efforts.
How do I share these dart library as closed source, so no one can see my source code?

Is there a way to hide my source code ?

Comment: I'm also wondering about this (hence the bounty). All the documentation about creating packages seems to assume you are creating open source work.

Comment: I suspect it's not supported (from reading the docs), but we'll see what people say. I've also filed a feature request: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51362.

Comment: It seems it´s not possible right know, but does that really keep you from monetizing? Shouldn´t it work to host the library in a private git repository and only grant access to paying customers?

Comment: @Josh No any one who has access to GIT can see my source. Why should I share my source with my clients, there developer will be easily be able to see my code and recreate it. [As I have created a very good documentation for my product].

Comment: To begin with, running `pub get` download the sources visible to anyone. Anything else would break tree-shaking

Comment: It may be easier to switch to a different business model or search for a different. To begin with, this would degrade the developer experience. Maybe give buyers a unique key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to distribute closed source flutter package.

I've received an answer from dartlang dev here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42863

Answer (score 1):

The way I've been doing it is using git as a provider for my dependencies.

For example, `fluttertoast` here is a private dart library:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  splashscreen:
  fluttertoast:
    git: git@github.com:androidfanatic/FlutterToast.git
```

I just had to make sure that other people who were working with me had access to the git repo and then their flutter environment was able to just use the library.

There are a bunch of dependency sources that we can use like package servers and packages on local system but I've only ever used git for sharing private flutter libraries.

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-sources

Comment: Still any one will be able to read your source, who has access to your GIT. For example someone who can use "Windows OS" still do not have access to "Windows OS" source code.

Comment: Two questions: 1- Should the repo be public for this to work if not, what is the authorization process? 2- Could this work as a microservice infrastructure as in, I want  to write library-like services and reference them in different flutter apps?

Comment: @Eren The repo can be private, you need to ensure that people have access to the repo i.e. they can "git pull" via their own key or using a limited password token etc. I do see it work in a microservice sort of architecture.

Comment: @Manish Is there a good and currently maintained dart backend framework you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to publish closed source flutter library. It includes dart source code but it is distributed as C/C++ library in binary form according to the instructions mentioned in their official documentation here.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop